# Django, inherit models.Model first or non model class first?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Sometimes I see

```
class Foo(models.Model, NonModelCls):
    pass
```

Other times, I see

```
class Bar(NonModelCls, models.Model):
    pass
```

What's the difference between the two and when should I use each over another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you have in `NonModelCls`. Search order for attributes and methods are from left to right (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html?highlight=inheritence#multiple-inheritance).

Let's say you have these classes:

```
class A:
    def __init__():
        print('A')
        super(A, self).__init__()


class B:
    def __init__():
        print('B')
        super(B, self).__init__()


class C(A,B):
    pass

class D(B,A):
    pass
```

Then calling C and D will result in:

```
>>>C()
A
B
<__main__.C object at 0x7f51d3efe0f0>
>>>D()
B
A
<__main__.D object at 0x7f51d3efe0b8>
```

So in your case, if `NonModelCls` has a method with same name as one of `models.Model` methods, like `save`, then it will override `Model.save` in `Bar` class, while it gets ignored in `Foo` class.